# MATLAB: efficient way to flip the sign of eigenvectors

Tags: matlab, performance, eigenvector

```
[V D] = eig(A)
```

gives eigenvectors with non-consistent sign, sometimes the first entry is positive, sometimes negative. It's OK for general purpose, but unfortunately for my job I need the signs to be consistent. For example in a series of such evaluations for different `A`. For example, I hope the first entries of all eigenvectors to be positive. What are some efficient ways to achieve this?

Here is what I think: An if-else statement to flip the sign (if 1st entry is negative, flip). But it seems not efficient as I have to evaluate eigenvectors many times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, in general eigenvalues and eigenvectors can be complex. This should be taken into account when we talk about [`sign`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sign.html). Here I assume you want the first element of all the eigenvectors to be *real* and *positive*.

This could be vectorized using [`bsxfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) in this way:

```
[V, D] = eig(A);
% get the sign of the first row:
signs = sign(V(1, :));
% multiply all columns by the complex conjugate of sign of the first element:
V = bsxfun(@times, V, conj(signs));
```

#### Benchmarking:

If you compare the speed of this method with a loop of `if` statement, you will see that my suggestion is a bit slower. But to be fare, this method should be compared with an equivalent loop which is capable of processing complex values. This is the results of my test:

```
% the loop solution:
for ii = 1:size(V, 2)
        V(:, ii) = V(:, ii) * conj(sign(V(1, ii)));
end

% A = rand(2);
------------------- With BSXFUN
Elapsed time is 0.744195 seconds.
------------------- With LOOP
Elapsed time is 0.500803 seconds.

% A = rand(10);
------------------- With BSXFUN
Elapsed time is 0.828464 seconds.
------------------- With LOOP
Elapsed time is 0.835429 seconds.

% A = rand(100);
------------------- With BSXFUN
Elapsed time is 1.421716 seconds.
------------------- With LOOP
Elapsed time is 4.286256 seconds.
```

As you see, it depends on your application. If you have many many small matrices, the loop solution looks more convenient. On the other hand, if you are dealing with bigger matrices, definitely a vectorized solution does the job more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the first element to determine the sign and flip the matrix:

```
 [V, D] = eig(A * sign(A(1)));
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Only timing will tell what performs better, but complexity wise it is very efficient to look at the first element, and only operate on the whole vector if you find that it has the wrong sign.

So if you would have

```
E = rand(n)-0.5;
```

Then this solution:

```
if E(1)<0
   E = -E;
end
```

would operate on 1+n/2 elements on average

Whilst something like

```
E = E * sign(E(1))
```

would operate on 1+n elements.

That being said, I would be surprised if you find a speed difference that is worth the optimization, so feel free to go for the most intuitive solution.

Comment: Note that if you have many vectors that can be processed individually, it may be slightly more efficient to store them all first and only flip the sign at the end.